# Create pixel art!

Tags: code-golf, graphical-output

## The task

Given an image as input, your task is to do the following:

1. Resize the image so it is **At least** 2 times smaller, but still has the same width/height ratio by taking every second (if resized to 2x) pixel in both horizontal and vertical directions and using those in the pixel art image. Example:

```
a 4x4 image 

[abcd
,efgh
,ijkl
,mnop]

When resized to 2x will become one of the following:

[ac  [bd  [eg  [fh
,ik] ,jl] ,mo] ,np]
```

2. Each RGB pixel in the newly resized image must be converted to a 3-bit color, so there are 8 different possible colors:

```
Red        (255,0,0)
Green      (0,255,0)
Blue       (0,0,255)
Light Blue (0,255,255)
Magenta    (255,0,255)
Yellow     (255,255,0)
White      (255,255,255)
Black      (0,0,0)
```

An image of the colors:

[image: 3bit colors]

3. And output the resulting image.

## Input

Your input may be:

1. An image
2. A path to the inputting image

## Output

Can be:

1. An image
2. A path to the outputting image

## Rules

- The inputting image will not be larger than 2048x2048 and will always be at least 256x256
- The outputting image must be at least 64x64
- When changing pixels, the original pixel **must** be converted to the closest (euclidean) pixel in the 3-bit scheme, no randomization
- You may hardcode how much you resize the image if you want to
- When submitting your answer, please include the following:

  1. Your byte-count in the title
  2. Your code
  3. An pair of images, one original of your choice and the other being the "pixel-art" from that image
- This is code-golf, so lowest byte count for each language wins.

## Test cases

[image: flower]
[image: flower]
(2x resize)

[image: tracer]
[image: tracer]
(2x resize)

Comment: @Noodle9 will edit and clarify, the resizing works by taking every second (if resized to 2x) pixel from the original image.

Comment: What is the metric used for "closest" for colors? What stops us from outputting an 1x1 image?

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate When i made an ungolfed version of this, I used (r//128*255,g//128*255,b//128*255) for (r,g,b) in every pixel (python). As for the size, will add in rules to output at least 64x64 image

Comment: @Noodle9 added an explanation in the post

Comment: @Noodle9 It can, updating the examples

Comment: I will repeat @mypronounismonicareinstate : What stops us from outputting a 1x1 image since the ratio is ours to decide?

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire please read the updated rules

Comment: @Noodle9 as i've answered, what i've used in python was for each channel n//128*255, where n is an rgb channel. However, it is up to you to decide how you define closest

Comment: @Noodle9 an rgb channel is simple - each pixel (usually) has three channels: RedGreenBlue, hence the name

Comment: @Noodle9 yep, gonna put euclidean. As for matrixes, only images allowed

Comment: Looks good! +1 (removed my comments).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Sledgehammer, <s>22</s> 17 bytes

<sup>I noticed I'm no longer winning for some reason and made a minor IO golf</sup>

```
⢟⢡⡂⠴⠒⢂⢜⠧⣘⡨⡏⣻⢈⠯⣧⠼⡫
```

Corresponding Mathematica code: `Export[".bmp",ImageAdjust[Import[#]~Downsample~2, 9!]]&` . Takes input from the file with name specified in the program's arguments (for some reason these are put in a file, too), outputs to the file `.bmp`. There are literally built-ins for everything!

- built-in for reading arbitrary image format
- built-in for downsampling
- built-in for adjusting the contrast by \$9!\$
- built-in for writing all that into a file

At least it's not `PixelArtify[Input[]]`.

## Mathematica, <s>61</s> 31 bytes

```
ImageAdjust[#~Downsample~2,9!]&
```

Adjusts the contrast of the downsampled image by the factorial of nine.

Comment: I guess my answer helped you to remove Import/Export

Comment: I included them in the Sledgehammer code because while I could input and output a bunch of pixel values, that's not very kind, and that answer is probably winning anyway, so I could sacrifice a few bytes for that purpose.

Answer (score 9):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 18 bytes

```
Yi2Lt3:K$)127>o2YG
```

The input is a string with the file name. The output is an image displayed in a window.

Input image:

[image]

Output image:

[image]

#### Explanation

```
Yi    % Implicit input: filename. Read image. Gives an N×M×3 uint8 array
2L    % Push [2 2 j] (predefined literal). When interpreted as an index,
      % this means 2:2:end
t     % Duplicate
3:    % Push [1 2 3]
K$)   % 4-input indexing. Downsamples the image by a factor of 2 in each
      % dimension of the first two dimensions (vertical and horizontal),
      % while keeping the three colour components
127>  % Greater than 127? Gives true (1) or false (0)
o     % Convert to double
2YG   % Display image. For double data type this assumes range from 0 to 1
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) + [imageio](http://imageio.github.io), <s>68</s> 67 bytes

Takes the filename as input, overwrites the original file.

```python
from imageio import*
lambda f:imwrite(f,(~imread(f)[::2,::2]>>7)-1)
```

`imageio.imread` returns a numpy 3d array of unsigned 8-bit integers corresponding to the RGB value of each pixel. `array[::2, ::2]` takes every other row and every other column of the array.

Because of the 8-bit data type `(~array>>7)-1` is equivalent to `((255-array)//128-1)%256`.

[image source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Supernumerary_rainbow_03_contrast.jpg)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it me or this output is not downsampled?

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate I displayed a downscaled version of the original because it took up so much space, the true original would open if you click on it. I have changed this now because this will probably confuse more people.

Comment: Damn, i also used python 3 but used PIL as it's the only image library I know. Well done!

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 69 bytes

```
Image[#&@@Nearest[{0,1}~Tuples~3,#]&/@#&/@ImageData@Downsample[#,2]]&
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I out-builtinned you!

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate yes, I forgot about downsample...

Answer (score 4):

## Java 10, <s>255</s> <s>254</s> <s>252</s> <s>251</s> 248 bytes

```java
import java.awt.image.*;I->{int w=I.getWidth()/2,h=I.getHeight()/2,c[]={0,255,65535,65280,255<<16,16711935,16776960,-1>>>8};var r=new BufferedImage(w,h,13,new IndexColorModel(3,8,c,0,0>1,1,0));r.createGraphics().drawImage(I,0,0,w,h,null);return r;}
```

-2 bytes thanks to *@mypronounismonicareinstate*
-4 bytes thanks to *@OlivierGrégoire*.

**Some example I/O:**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I/O as a `java.awt.image.BufferedImage`.

**Explanation:**

```java
import java.awt.image.*;      // Import for BufferedImage and IndexColorModel
I->{                          // Method with BufferedImage as both parameter & return
  int w=I.getWidth()/2,       //  Get the width/2 of the input-image
      h=I.getHeight()/2,      //  Get the height/2 of the input-image
      c[]={                   //  Integer-arry for the colors:
       0,                     //   0x000000 (black)
       255,                   //   0x0000ff (blue)
       65535,                 //   0x00ff00 (green)
       65280,                 //   0x00ffff (aqua)
       255<<16,               //   0xff0000 (red)
       16711935,              //   0xff00ff (magenta)
       16776960,              //   0xffff00 (yellow)
       -1>>>8};               //   0xffffff (white)
  var r=new BufferedImage(w,h,//  Create the return-BufferdImage with this size, and:
         13,                  //   An indexed byte image (BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED)
         new IndexColorModel( //   Using the following ColorModel:
          3,                  //    3-bits
          8,c,                //    with the 8 colors of the earlier created array
          0,                  //    without an offset index
          0>1,                //    without alpha layers (false)
          1,                  //    without transparent colors (Transparency.OPAQUE)
          0));                //    using unsigned bytes as data (DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE)
  r.createGraphics()          //  Convert this image to a Graphics2D object
   .drawImage(I,              //  So we can use the input-image for it
              0,0,            //   with 0,0 as starting x,y coordinates
              w,h,            //   the same halved width & height
              null);          //   and no ImageObserver
  return r;}                  //  Return this created BufferedImage as result
```

Comment: Are the last 3 parameters of `IndexColorModel` necessary?

Comment: Does something like `-1u>>8` work for 16777215?

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire I'm afraid so. The [constructors of the `IndexColorModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/IndexColorModel.html) are limited when using an `int[]` for the colors. It's either `(int,int,int[],int,boolean,int,int)` or `int,int,int[],int,int,BigInteger)`. It also has a constructor with `byte[]`, but those can't fit some of the colors, and the three separated parameters for `red`,`green`,`blue`, but I doubt those would save bytes considering the three loose arrays.

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate Thanks, that indeed works (although it's `>>>` instead of `u>>` in Java). I tried to find something shorter for some of those numbers, but didn't really worked out. Thanks!

Comment: Ok for the constructors, I hadn't noticed the change from byte[] to int[]. Also, same idea as @mypronounismonicareinstate: `255<<16 == 16711680`.

Comment: `,c[]={0,255,65535,65280,255<<16,16711935,16776960,-1>>>8}` and use `c` instead of `new int[]{...}`.

Comment: Does this use the correct downscaling algorithm?

Answer (score 3):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), <s>150</s> 148 bytes

```
func[s][r: func[a][round/to a 255]i: load s forall i[i/1: as-rgba r i/1/1
r i/1/2 r i/1/3 0]view compose[base(i/size / 2)draw[scale .5 .5 image i]]]
```

The output is an image displayed in a window.

[image: Figure]
Original

[image: Figure x.5]
Scale 0.5

[image: Samoyed]
Original

[image: Samoyed x 0.5]
Scale x 0.5

Comment: That downsampled dog is pretty scary looking :p

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms It's the first time I hear someone to call a samoyed dog "scary looking" :) It's good that you were talking about the downsampled one.
I have a samoyed dog myself, not as fluffy as the one above though and still she's adorable!

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3 + PIL, <s>211</s> 208 bytes

```
from PIL import Image as I
i=I.open(input(),'r')
p=i.load()
q,g=i.size;a=q//4;c=g//4
u=I.new('RGB',(a,c))
o=u.load()
for w in range(a):
 for h in range(c):o[w,h]=tuple(e//128*255 for e in p[w*4,h*4])
u.show()
```

Golfed the testing script I used to create the test cases for this challenge

Comment: When you post a challenge, it's good to let a few days before you post your try, so that people can try in all the languages they want.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire I don't see how this answer prevents people from answering...

Answer (score 3):

### bash + ImageMagick, <s>123</s> 50 bytes

```
convert "$1" -sample 50% +dither -posterize 2 "$2"
```

Untested, as I haven't actually installed it; I've just cribbed stuff from Stack Overflow. Edit: Saved 73 bytes thanks to @someone.

Comment: There's the `-posterize` flag that probably does the equivalent of the `red,lime,blue,...` thingy (I don't understand that line properly though).

Comment: @someone What that line did was to generate an image with that palette so that the input image could be converted to the same palette.

Comment: I think the double quotes are unnecessary (on this website). Mogrify instead of convert can probably save a few bytes too.

Answer (score 3):

## bash + [netpbm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm), 30 bytes

```
pnmdepth 1|pnmscale -nomix 0.5
```

Takes input on stdin as a PNM file, and outputs on stdout as a PNM file.

`pnmdepth 1` reduces the depth of the image on its stdin to 1, and `pnmscale 0.5` reduces the size by a half in each direction. The `-nomix` option is required for `pnmscale` to choose a pixel from the starting image for each output pixel, instead of mixing adjacent input pixels into one output pixel.

Comment: Does it parse `.5` as 0.5? (I haven't tried)

Answer (score 1):

## MATLAB, 32 bytes

```
@(x)(x(1:2:end,1:2:end,:)>127)*1
```

Both input and output are images. Output is an array storing image data, it's not specified in challenge that output image must be displayed. (to display result add 8 bytes for `imshow(`...`)` command)
The actual result and original:
[image: input image]
[image: output image]

Art credit to [Janna Sophia](https://www.artstation.com/jannasophia).

Answer (score 0):

## Processing, 463 bytes

```
size(500,500);String u="";PImage p=loadImage(u);p.resize(p.width/2,p.height/2);noStroke();color[]c={#ff0000,#00ff00,#0000ff,#00ffff,#ff00ff,#ffff00,#ffffff,0};p.loadPixels();for(int i=0;i<p.width;i++){for(int j=0;j<p.height;j++){float[]d=new float[8];color x=p.get(i,j);for(int k=0;k<8;k++)d[k]=sqrt(sq(red(x)-red(c[k]))+sq(blue(x)-blue(c[k]))+sq(green(x)-green(c[k])));int b=0;for(int l=0;l<8;l++){if(d[l]<=d[b]){b=l;}}fill(c[b]);rect(i,j,1,1);}}save(u+"1.png");
```

Takes image location, saves pixel art as image1.png.
[image][image]
Image from [beeple.](https://www.beeple-crap.com/)